# two vertical inputs share a common button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]I have a form, in that n number of form fields available. only For 2 inputs, I want to share a common button without affecting remaining layout, but it's not aligned properly as common.

[Here](https://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/abwqodp) is what I tried. First two input fields should have common button

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
<div class="form-group pt-4">   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
</div>  
   <div class="col">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by common button? Could you attach a photo showing what you want?

Comment: height of the button should match the 2 input fields

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to center the button for two input elements. Is that so you can try `display:table` for the `.row` this might have fix your issue.

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row .col{
  display: table-cell;
}

.col1 {
  width: 40%;
}

.col2 {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.col2 button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.css" >
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">
<div class="form-group pt-4">
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
</div>
 
  
   <div class="col col2">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button> 
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

However if you want to increase the size for the button you can always add padding or set height for the button.

Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/WNOMeXe?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

Pure `bootstrap 4` impementation wll be the one below.

You have to group the two inputs into one single `.col` and the button to an another `.col` with `flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-1 mb-3 d-flex` to shrink the container to the minimum of button width and to have sufficient margin at bottom.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group pt-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-1 mb-3 d-flex">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @G.L.P If this is what you are looking for, please approve this answer. Happy to have an upvote aswell.

Answer (score 1):

`col-auto` in bootrap `4.0.0` does not have `padding`. And there may be some other bugs too. You should better use the latest version of bootstrap 4. it is version `4.6.0`

---

Use two `.row`. The first `.row` for the first two inputs and the button and the second `.row` for the rest of the inputs.

Use `.col-auto` and `.d-flex` for the column that contains the button to make it take as much space at it need and full height

Use `.mb-3` for the button since the `.form-group` has that much margin-bottom.

You may use `.btn-outline-secondary` instead of `.btn-secondary`

```
  <div class="col-auto d-flex ">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
  </div>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group pt-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto d-flex">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Doing so you avoid multiple nesting of `.row` and `.col`.

Answer (score 1):

here is another approach, also  rethinking the structure with only BS class for the styling

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col  ">
      <div class="form-group pt-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row pl-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. But you do not follow bootstrap's convention.

Comment: @mahan no, i follow the flex possibilities, properties and BS is build on flex mainly.